# TextView in the bottom of the LinearLayout

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to put the `textview` at the bottom of the layout, but it doesn't work.
Please help me to get the `textview` to the bottom of the screen.
I tried gridlayout but I don't really understand the way to use it.

Thank you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/background1" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Tour Main Menu"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_large" />   
    </LinearLayout> 

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tour_info"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="There are 47 Passengers"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium" />   

    </LinearLayout> 

    <TableLayout  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >"

                <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/passenger_list"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:background="@drawable/icon"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/pass_list"  />    

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/passenger_list_text"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/pass_list"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/arrivals"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:background="@drawable/icon"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:padding="44dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/arrivals" />

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/arrivals_text"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/arrivals"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/departures"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/icon"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/departures" />

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/departures_text"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/departures"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium" />    .

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/master_rooming"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/icon"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/rooming" />

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/master_rooming_text"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/rooming"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium" />        
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="50dp" >


            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >"

                <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/itinerary"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/icon"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/itinerary" />   

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/itinerary_text"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/itinerary"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium" />    

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/qa"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/icon"
                        android:contentDescription="QA" />  

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/qa_text"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="QA"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/icon"
                        android:contentDescription="QA" />  

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Text Here"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/icon"
                        android:contentDescription="QA" />  

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Text Here"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow> 
    </TableLayout>


    <!-- Time Stamp at the bottom of the screen -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeStamp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: give `layout_gravity` a shot?.. also, you've got this textview in a linearlayout; I'de recommend containing everything within a relative layout (and then alignParentBottom=true + gravity) OR use a framelayout, and use `layout_gravity`.

Comment: Yes, follow  Nirvana Tikku's suggestion to wrap the whole thing in a RelativeLayout rather than a LinearLayout and use alignParentBottom=true on the TextView.

Comment: I also did relative layout before, but if I use the relative layout on a different dpi screen, it will look different correct? I'm trying to keep the same look on different devices.

Comment: "the same look" <-- wouldn't you expect the textview to be at the bottom of the screen, then? a relative layout will give you the flexibility to define the positioning of items, and will scale proportionally..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="0"
        >
    ...   
    </LinearLayout> 

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="0"
        >
    ...   
    </LinearLayout> 

    <TableLayout  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    ...   
    </TableLayout>


    <!-- Spacer: stretches causing the TextView below to move to the bottom of the screen -->
    <View 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />

    <!-- Time Stamp at the bottom of the screen -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeStamp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The idea is to attach `android:layout_weight` to each child of `LinearLayout`. All of them have a weight of 0, meaning, they do *not* stretch to fill available space. Except one, the View. It has a weight of 1, meaning it will receive *all available space and stretch*, effectively moving the `TextView` below to the bottom.

Comment: Note that you could get rid of the spacer View and attach android:layout_weight="1" to one of the already existing children in your layout, allowing them to stretch so that the last child (TextView) will be put on the bottom.